# ¿Que me recomiendan para hacer este tipo de selects anidados?

Tags: php, mysqli, formularios, select

Estoy diseñando un formulario bastante complejo, con dentro bastantes consultas sql.

Necesito crear muchos selects anidados.

El caso, actualmente utilizo "onchange.. this form submit"..
Para ir enviando por POST la información de uno a otro.

El caso, que no me interesa que se envie el form cada vez que cambio un select, me gustaría que al hacer clic, me vaya obteniendo los datos de forma asincrona y poder ir rellenando los selects sin tener que enviar el form entero..

Son muchos selects que van anidados entonces querría saber que tipo de lenguaje me recomiendan utilizar.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Veo que es entorno web, puedes hacer uso de `AJAX` así evitarías que tu pagina se recargue cada que seleccionas un item de algún `select`

Comment: Voy a plantearlo, también había pensado en ajax, pero quería alguna opinión más, muchas gracias

Comment: Sintiendolo mucho voto para cerrar, la pregunta se basa en opiniones. En cuanto a tu pregunta podrias utilizar alguna libreria js para facilitar el trabajo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con `JQuery`, te voy a poner un ejemplo simple que yo realice con `Estados` y `Condados` donde seleccionas un estado y en un `Select` distinto te despliega los condados correspondientes a ese estado.

Descripción del código: Tengo un formulario el cual en el `Select` de los estados ya previamente envío los datos para mostrar todos los estados en ese `Select` por medio de `PHP`, en `JQuery` le digo que si el `SelectState` cambia entonces vacié el `SelectCounty` y a ese mismo le agregue los datos que traiga la consulta del `getJSON`, para esto la `URL` que estoy agregando en el `getJSON` ya me retorna los datos de los `Condados` por medio del `Value`que tiene el `SelectState`.

Código `HTML` y `PHP`:

```
<form id="form" action="<?echo base_url('index/savePost')?>" method="post">
    <p class="spaceleft">State:</p>
    <div class="centered">
        <select id="selectState" class="select" name="form[state]" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected value>Select One</option>
            <?php foreach($States as $State){?>
                <option value="<?php echo $State['id']?>"><?php echo $State['name']?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <p class="spaceleft">County:</p>
    <div class="centered">
        <select id="selectCounty" class="select" name="form[county]" disabled required>
            <option value="" disabled selected value>Select One</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="centeredlimit">
        <button type="submit" class="auto-style2">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Código `JS`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var selectState = $('#selectState');
    var selectCounty = $('#selectCounty');

    selectState.change(function() {
        selectCounty.empty();
        selectCounty.append('<option value="" disabled selected value>Select One</option>');
        $.getJSON('<?php echo base_url('Index/getCountiesJson?id=')?>'+selectState.val(),function(data){
            $.each(data.Counties, function(index,value){
                selectCounty.append('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
            });
            selectCounty.prop('disabled', false);
        });
    });

});
```

En este caso yo tengo solo el `SelectState` activado y el otro `SelectCounty` lo tengo en `Disabled` por eso utilizo `selectCounty.prop('disabled', false);` para que ahora este activo el `Select`.